# Merge objects from two arrays of object based in the index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i searched a lot about this but i do not find anything that can enlight me about my issue:

I have this code:

```js
let array1 = ["a", "b", 3, {
    p1: 'hola'
  }, "c", "d"],
  array2 = [1, 2, {
    p1: 'adios'
  }],
  result = [],
  i, l = Math.min(array1.length, array2.length);


for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (typeof array1[i] === 'object' && typeof array2[i] === 'object') {
    result.push(array2[i], ...(JSON.stringify() === JSON.stringify() ?
      [] :
      [array1[i]]
    ));
  } else {
    result.push(array2[i], array1[i]);
  }

}
result.push(...array1.slice(l), ...array2.slice(l));

console.log(result);
```

i have modified the code with the suggestions, right now the code does this:

we have two array;

array1 = ["a", "b", 3, {p1: 'hello'},"c", "d"]
array2 = [1, 2,  {p1: 'hello'}]

the result right now is this based in the code:

result: [1, 'a', 2, 'b', {p1: 'hello'}, 3, {p1: 'hello'}, 'c', 'd']

this work fine because i dont want to omit objects that are in different index between the two array, the problem right now is that when the objects in the two array are in the same index this code;

array1 = ["a", "b", {p2: 'goodbye'},"c", "d"]
array2 = [1, 2,  {p1: 'hello'}]

result : [1, 'a', 2, 'b', {p1: 'hello'}, 'c', 'd']

This is my issue right now, what i want is that when there are object in the same index on two array compare the properties of the objects and is the same skip the first array object and pass the second to the final array, but if the properties are not the same, combine the properties of the object in one, this is the ideal result that i want:

array1 = ["a", "b", {p2: 'goodbye'},"c", "d"]
array2 = [1, 2,  {p1: 'hello'}]

result : [1, 'a', 2, 'b', {p1: 'hello', p2: 'goodbye'}, 'c', 'd']

Comment: Can't you just add an `if` statement inside the `for` to check if the two are the same, and if they are, only push on one of them instead of both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```js
let array1 = ['a', 'b', { p2: 'goodbye' }, 'c', 'd'];
let array2 = [1, 2, { p1: 'hello' }];

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(array1.length, array2.length); i++) {
  if (typeof array1[i] == 'object' && typeof array2[i] == 'object') {
    result.push({ ...array2[i], ...array1[i] });
  } else {
    array2[i] && result.push(array2[i]);
    array1[i] && result.push(array1[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the items and if same omit the second item.

```js
let array1 = ["a", "b", {p1: 'hello world'},"c", "d"],
    array2 = [1, 2,  {p1: 'hello world'}],
    result = [],
    i, l = Math.min(array1.length, array2.length);
    
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    result.push(array2[i], ...(JSON.stringify() === JSON.stringify()
        ? []
        : [array1[i]]
    ));
}
result.push(...array1.slice(l), ...array2.slice(l));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but  this way simply delete if they are objects, what i want is to omit one of the object only if have the same properties(maybe is my fault for not describe the issue well)

Comment: please add different use cases and wanted results.